# Unable to find dot product of two matrix (W and H from NMF ) with same inner dimensions

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication, dimensionality-reduction, nmf

I am doing Non-Negative Matrix Factorization (NMF) of a matrix **A** in R. It has Genes on rows and Samples on the columns. For NMF, I am using the [CRAN package `NMF`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NMF/index.html). Once the basis matrix **W** and coefficient matrix **H** are computed, I want to check whether the factorisation was accurate enough. For that, I am trying to calculate the dot product of **W** and **H** so as to check whether I can get the original matrix **A** back.

Although the inner dimensions of basis matrix **W** and coefficient matrix **H** are same `(rank = 3)`, I cannot multiply them. I keep getting the following error. This one line error is not very helpful.

```
Error in x * y : non-conformable arrays
```

**Reproducible code**

```
# Make a 10 * 10 matrix
ranVal= sample(1:10,100,replace =T)
M=matrix(ranVal,nrow=10)

# Rename the rows and columns
rownames(M) <-  paste(rep("gene", 10),c(1:10), sep = "_")
colnames(M) <-  paste(rep("sample", 10),c(1:10), sep = "_")

# See how it looks
M

# NMF
library(NMF)
tempRes <- nmf(x = M, rank = 3, .options = c("pv"))

# NMF implementation from Brunet et al. (2004)
result <- nmf_update.brunet_R(i = 1, v = M, x = tempRes, eps=.Machine$double.eps)

# Basis Matrix
W <- .basis(result); 

# Coeff Matrix
H <- .coef(result)

# Checking dimensions
dim(W)
dim(H)

# Dot product
A <- W*H # Error: non-conformable arrays
A <- geometry::dot(W,H) # Error: non-conformable arrays
```

How should I go about it? Is there a different way to check it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `W %*% H`?

```
W %*% H
        sample_1 sample_2   sample_3 sample_4  sample_5 sample_6
gene_1  4.406480 6.392739  9.5742884 5.164528  5.074363 3.549958
gene_2  7.165909 4.960877  2.3608356 5.718255  8.405870 5.817709
gene_3  5.070350 3.804750  3.2464367 3.906296  6.383760 4.810851
gene_4  8.356959 4.181312  0.9964025 5.167783 10.955091 8.533261
gene_5  4.671284 5.157582 11.0938515 3.059027  7.946619 7.730591
gene_6  5.899437 6.666820  6.0368747 6.705011  5.718862 2.998982
gene_7  7.801179 7.052729  1.3482074 8.775604  6.398204 2.076385
gene_8  3.501642 4.410587  9.1595473 2.720517  5.693630 5.401830
gene_9  5.271008 7.975740  9.1787413 7.358409  4.472696 1.753683
gene_10 5.855654 4.396895  1.0050132 5.424544  5.950780 3.326661
        sample_7 sample_8  sample_9 sample_10
gene_1  6.781347 5.909006  8.431049  4.716241
gene_2  4.884002 6.815600  4.339132  4.531809
gene_3  4.015448 5.548575  3.376917  2.836615
gene_4  4.446931 8.554956  1.793168  3.014138
gene_5  6.644475 8.692351  5.003496  1.000724
gene_6  6.364861 5.479570  8.536569  6.593015
gene_7  5.804209 4.769660  8.798081  9.175741
gene_8  5.469769 6.475237  4.801630  1.365611
gene_9  7.673524 5.183927 11.371303  7.760969
gene_10 3.915477 4.571069  4.548770  5.005138
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Do you have any thoughts on why ```%*%``` works but not ```*``` or ```geometry::dot()```? They do the same thing, don't they?

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand the matrix multiplication that you are trying to achieve in this particular case, but for basic multiplication, R uses `%*%` for data with `matrix` class, and `*` for data with `numeric` of `integer` class, so they are not interchangeable.  To see how it differs, use them for two square matrices. For example: `A <- matrix(1:4, 2)` and `B <- matrix(5:8, 2)` and then `A %*% B` vs `A * B`.

Comment: Okay, that explains why it wasn't working. Thanks for the solution! I believe it was more of a syntactical error.